# Should switching users switch TTY as well?

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, switch-user

In trying to troubleshoot user switching hangs and irregularity's I noticed if I log in as user A then switch to user B, and then press,  (TTY7) will take me directly back to the unlock prompt for user A.  (TTY8) will bring me to user B's X session. Adding user C to the mix adds  (TTY9).

Is this how user switching is suppose to work or is something not configured properly on my system? Aren't there only supposed to be 7 TTY sessions configured? I think this is the cause of my user switching issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast user switching opens another X server on the next available VT. There are at least 24 available VTs on a Linux system.